# How to deploy django Project on Live server?

Tags: django, python-3.x, server, web-deployment, ip-address

This is my first time when I am deploying my site on the live server(my company server). I have built small django project which I want to deploy on my company server. can anyone tell me how to do it because when I have tried the 'python manage.py runsever ipaddressofservermachine, it is working on server machine but it is not working in other laptops. i thought it should have worked but it did not.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved as Port which I was using of server machine was not available for use.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you came across this than you can use py manage.py 0.0.0.0:port# and in your settings.py add your ip and your local host interfaces e.g

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.4.53','localhost','127.0.0.1' ].

This will expose your app to all the availble ip adresses but the app can only be accesed through the interface you specify.

https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

Answer (score 0):

What web server / env you use in your job?
here some tutorials for both windows server - IIS deploy:
[Django over IIS Deploy](https://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial)

and then you have Linux env to deploy on:[Linux Django Deploy - UBUNTU](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)
and here is full documentation about deploying django on Nginx + Integration with Github:
[Nginx Django Deploy](https://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html)

Comment: I am using django default server. i have just tried this command "python manage.py runserver ipofmycompanyservermachine".